# How to create secrets using Kubernetes Python client?

Tags: python, json, kubernetes, openapi, kubernetes-python-client

I have been trying to play around with creating secrets for Kubernetes cluster using the python client. I keep getting an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "create_secrets.py", line 19, in <module>
api_response = v1.create_namespaced_secret(namespace, body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 7271, in create_namespaced_secret
(data) = self.create_namespaced_secret_with_http_info(namespace, body, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 7361, in create_namespaced_secret_with_http_info
collection_formats=collection_formats)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 335, in call_api
_preload_content, _request_timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 148, in __call_api
_request_timeout=_request_timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 393, in request
body=body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 287, in POST
body=body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 240, in request
raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Mon, 16 Oct 2017 04:17:35 GMT', 'Content-Length': '234'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"none in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Secret: no kind \"none\" is registered for version \"v1\"","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

This is my code that I am trying to execute to create a secret.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import kubernetes.client
from pprint import pprint
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
namespace = 'kube-system'
metadata = {'name': 'pk-test-tls', 'namespace': 'kube-system'}
data=  {'tls.crt': '###BASE64 encoded crt###', 'tls.key': '###BASE64 encoded Key###'}
api_version = 'v1'
kind = 'none'
body = kubernetes.client.V1Secret(api_version, data , kind, metadata, 
type='kubernetes.io/tls')

api_response = v1.create_namespaced_secret(namespace, body)
pprint(api_response)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everything that you have written is alright but pay attention to the message received from `kube-apiserver`:

> HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"none in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: no kind "none" is registered for version "v1"","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}

Especially **no kind "none"**. Is it just typo or do you have something on your mind here?

You have list of kinds here https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#types-kinds

If you change kind to "Secret" then everything will be working fine.

Comment: I took your advice and changed the kind = Secret and got the following error. HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Secret in version \"none\" cannot be handled as a Secret: no kind \"Secret\" is registered for version \"none\"","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}

Comment: I then changed the api_version to v1 and that fixed it.

Comment: You have the `api_version` = "v1" in original post.

Comment: @3h4x why is doesn't accept string_data. I gettin following error. `{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Secret in version \"v1\" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.TypeMeta: Kind: Data: decode base64: illegal base64 data at input byte 12`


I passed string_data as argument, but it processing it as `Data` type not `stringData` type