# k8s/python: How do I read a secret using the Kubernetes Python client?

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook

I want to do the opposite of this question:

[How to create secrets using Kubernetes Python client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763148/how-to-create-secrets-using-kubernetes-python-client)

i.e.:

**How do I read an existing secret from a kubernetes cluster via the kubernetes-python API?**

The use case is: I want to authenticate to mongodb (running in my cluster) from a jupyter notebook (also running in my cluster) without, for obvious reasons, saving the mongodb auth password inside the jupyter notebook.

Thanks!

Comment: how about injecting the secrets as env variables to the pod? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-environment-variables

Answer (score 23):

1. Install [Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#kubernetes-python-client) for python
2. Now you can pull the secret. For example secret name - `mysql-pass`, namespace - `default`

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
secret = v1.read_namespaced_secret("mysql-pass", "default")
print(secret)
```

3. If you need to extract decoded password from the secret

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import base64
import sys    
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
sec = str(v1.read_namespaced_secret("mysql-pass", "default").data)
pas = base64.b64decode(sec.strip().split()[1].translate(None, '}\''))
print(pas)
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 8):

If you use kubernetes client api it will give you response as a dict datatype and you might not need to do spiting etc, You can say something like this,

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import base64
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
sec = v1.read_namespaced_secret("default-token-rsbq7", "default").data
cert = base64.b64decode(sec["ca.crt"])
print(cert)
```