# K8s Python Access Secret from inside Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

My question is the same of this question: [k8s/python: How do I read a secret using the Kubernetes Python client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159582/k8s-python-how-do-i-read-a-secret-using-the-kubernetes-python-client) but from inside Kubernetes. I know how to access secrets from the outside with kubernetes python client.

But how do I access a secret in python when inside kubernetes? I have several python microservices, and they should all access secrets from within kubernetes.
According to the official documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-environment-variables I can create environmental variables. Would these variables then be accessible through `import os; os["MY_VAR"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think your guess is right, and that if you deploy a pod with the [following configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-a-container-environment-variable-with-data-from-a-single-secret), then you will be able to access the environment variable `SECRET_USERNAME` within your pod. Then,

```py
import os
username = os.environ["SECRET_USERNAME"]
```

would allow you to access this value directly in python